# IntelliJ IDEA 12: CSS format on height is broken

Tags: css, intellij-idea

I like IDEA however its format on CSS3 distress me many times, it formats

```
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 45px);
height: -moz-calc(100% - 45px);
height: -o-calc(100% - 45px);
height: calc(100% - 45px);
```

to

```
height: -webkit-calc(100% -45px);
height: -moz-calc(100% -45px);
height: -o-calc(100% -45px);
height: calc(100% -45px);
```

which cause error every time(I turn auto format on so I have to fix it every time after i detect something is wrong).

And i can't find any place to correct this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in WebStorm](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6987).

Intellij IDEA includes WebStorm, so probably they share this bug. I can confirm it's still here in 12.1.

My advice is to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) instead of CSS. For some mysterious reason LESS files are not affected by this bug.

---

In order to make switching to LESS less of a pain (pun indeed, intended), there are some tips:

- CSS syntax will work with LESS, so basically you don't need to change your stylesheet at all
- you can configure [File Watcher](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-watchers.html), which will compile your LESS file on the fly, generating regular CSS file in the specified directory, so you don't even need to change the way you import your stylesheet in HTML